# Javascript -> Recursively find a substring within a string

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive program to count the number of times a substring ("cat") appears in a string ("catdogcowcat").  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
function strCount (str, sub) {
    var subLen = sub.length;
    var strLen = str.length;
    if (strLen < subLen) {
        return 0;
    } else if (str.slice(0, subLen) === sub) {
        return 1 + strCount(str.substring(subLen));
    } else return strCount(str.substring(1));
}
```

I think it's breaking when I try to get the length of the substring on this line, but that's just my guess based on my infantile understanding of devtools debugging:

```
return 1 + strCount(str.substring(subLen));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `strCount` function takes 2 arguments, so make sure you pass `sub` when you call it recursively:

```
function strCount (str, sub) {
    var subLen = sub.length;
    var strLen = str.length;
    if (strLen < subLen) {
        return 0;
    } else if (str.slice(0, subLen) === sub) {
        return 1 + strCount(str.substring(subLen), sub);
    } else return strCount(str.substring(1), sub);
}
```

Comment: Oops, shouldn't have missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression, with match instead of having to do a recursive function

```
function strCount(needle,haystack){
   var r = new RegExp(needle,"g");
   var r2 = haystack.match(r);
   return (r2?r2.length:0);
}

console.log( strCount("cat","catdowcowcat") );
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass value for sub ..

```
 function strCount(str, sub) {                
            var subLen = sub.length;
            var strLen = str.length;
            if (strLen < subLen) {
                return 0;
            } else if (str.slice(0, subLen) === sub) {
                return 1 + strCount(str.substring(subLen),sub);
            } else
                return strCount(str.substring(1),sub);
        }
```

you can call the method

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
               alert(strCount("catdogcowcat","cat"));
            });
```

It will return the result as 2.
Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/deepaksuresh3003/RDmby/

Answer (score 0):

you are calling your own method **strCount(str.substring(subLen))** without providing second parameter and hence the function is taking 'sub' parameter as undefined.

Update your code as follows and it will start working:

```
 function strCount(str, sub) {
        var subLen = sub.length;
        var strLen = str.length;
        if (strLen < subLen) {
            return 0;
        } else if (str.slice(0, subLen) === sub) {
            return 1 + strCount(str.substring(subLen), sub);
        } else return strCount(str.substring(1),sub);
    }
```